# How to handle the full set of websocket events in websocketd?

Tags: websocket

I was looking at using websocketd as a web sockets server, but I don't see how it can be used to respond to the full set of websocket events such as onerror and onclose.

Comment: Perhaps add a little context and some useful tags to your question.  What development environment and programming language are you talking about?  What is websocketd?

Comment: http://websocketd.com

Comment: It's a websocket daemon.  You write an app in whatever language you want and then use websocketd to daemonize it. It does read/write to stdin/stdout.  There is very little existing documentation though so it is unclear how to get any events other than on message or if it even supports it. Given knowledge of websocketd I think my question is enough. I would have tagged it with websocketd instead of websockets, but no such tag exists today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is not how it works.  You don't program websocketd and it doesn't have any events.  You use as a stand-alone tool to wrap some other program and then each incoming connection starts an instance of the program you've configured it to wrap.  Then, any incoming messages are send to stdin of that program and any stdout response from the program is sent back to the client that connected to the websocket server.  You can think of it like a tool that just forwards incoming websockets messages to stdin of your app and captures the output and forwards that back to the client.

As you presumably know, the idea is that without doing any server programming yourself, you could create a remote interface to any command line tool on your computer (with the associated caveats/risks that has) that expects to get its input from stdin and writes its output to stdout.  That remote interface could be in a web page or could be any other program you write that uses a webSocket to communicate with the websocketd server you configured and ran on your host.  So you only write the client-side of things.  The websocketd doc does not say what it does with output that it finds on stderr.

When a web socket client connects to this websocket server, an instance of your program will get started up.  So, in essence, the `onconnect` event is that your program started.  When the client disconnects, it will kill your program (that's essentially the `onclose` event).

It is not clear what it does if it gets webSocket errors in sending data back to the client.  You'd have to dissect the code here https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd to try to figure that out (it appears to be written in `go`.  Presumably, since it's a server itself and there's no interface, probably the most that happens is that the error is logged or maybe the webSocket is disconnected.  Without modifying the code, there's no provision for you to participate in what happens when there's a webSocket communication error.  The daemon has a preprogrammed behavior.

I do see examples [here in the code](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/blob/ac4b25f80b5b9abd4e6b904738dedfb196e2ca2b/libwebsocketd/process_endpoint.go#L130) where it deals with errors from reading `stdout` and it logs those errors and then closes the stdout stream.

The [code here](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/blob/ac4b25f80b5b9abd4e6b904738dedfb196e2ca2b/libwebsocketd/websocket_endpoint.go) appears to close the incoming webSocket if it gets errors while reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Websocket events like onclose and onerror are are handled via Javascript event handlers. The browser built in Javascript provides the Interface ! 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WebSocket
Some code examples:
https://www.bitkistl.com/2019/12/websocketd-example-with-better_27.html